# Entity Framework Migrations: get database version as string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a web app using EF5. I'd like to display the database version (i.e. the name of the migration) on the admin pages... that way, if the site is deployed to an environment where I don't have database admin rights, I can still log into the back end to find the version if I need to generate an upgrade script. Is there a property e.g. of the DBContext I can use to get this information?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Entity framework will create migration history table to manage the database version.

> Migrations history table is a table used by Code First Migrations to
>   store details about migrations applied to the database. By default the
>   name of the table in the database is __MigrationHistory and it is
>   created when applying the first migration do the database. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx)

You can use `MigrationId` column to be the database version. The value of the column looks like `201408011306353_InitialCreate`. Just get the last row order by the first 15 character descending.

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var query = "select top 1 MigrationId from __MigrationHistory order by LEFT(MigrationId, 15) desc";
    var migrationId = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: you may want to limit to the appropriate DbContext - i.e. query = "select top 1 MigrationId from __MigrationHistory where [dbo].[ContextKey] = '" + typeof(AppContext).FullName + "' order by LEFT(MigrationId, 15) desc"

Answer (score 13):

Entity framework core provides:

**context.Database.GetMigrations()**

> Gets all the migrations that are defined in the configured migrations assembly.

**context.Database.GetAppliedMigrations()**

> Gets all migrations that have been applied to the target database.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-2.0

Example

```
// _context = instance of MyDbContext from ctor

var lastAppliedMigration = _context.Database.GetAppliedMigrations().LastOrDefault();
var lastDefinedMigration = _context.Database.GetMigrations().LastOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"Last applied migration id: {lastAppliedMigration}");

Console.WriteLine(lastAppliedMigration == lastDefinedMigration
    ? "Database is up to date."
    : $"There are outstanding migrations. Last defined migration is: {lastDefinedMigration}");
```

Comment: The topic starter asked for EF5 but you suggested solution for EF Core.

Comment: @PavelNazarov - yes, that's why the answer starts with "entity framework core". This way people coming from google (like me before I wrote this answer) using the "more current" version of ef can find the "current" answer. The original question is from 2014 so I think it's not too confusing for the starter.

Comment: Strictly I'm not sure that the order of these are guaranteed, so I suggest to add an OrderBy to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

Getting last migrationId in Ef Core

```
_context.Database.GetMigrations().Last()
```